# PHP - Regex replacement throws an error (preg_replace)

Tags: php, regex, string

I need to remove some weird characters in a string pulled from a source database using a regex because these characters can be located anywhere in the string and can be a little different.
Here's my code right now:

```
$str = "LIVR DEC 20 23 $é**é$01$";
$result = preg_replace("/\$[^ ]+\$/", "", $str);
```

When testing it on [phpliveregex.com](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lbi), it works fine but when i run the code (using PHP 5.4), i get the following error:

```
PHP Notice: Undefined variable: é
```

and $result contains the original string. Why is it throwing that error?

Comment: Use single-quoted string literal to avoid string interpolation. Same with regex, use single quotes.

Comment: Thank you, replacing double quotes with single quotes in the regex did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `$str` and the regex inside single quoted string literals. Also, since you are working with Unicode strings, you should also use the `u` modifier:

```
$str = 'LIVR DEC 20 23 $é**é$01$';
$result = preg_replace('/\$[^ ]+\$/u', "", $str);
echo $result; // => LIVR DEC 20 23
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/WmExjZ).

Otherwise, when PHP engine sees `"$é"`, it wants to interpolate it, but cannot find the variable with this name.

The regex needs single quotes because `"/\$[^ ]+\$/"` is equal to `/$[^ ]+$/` where `$` are end of string anchors, and there can't be two different end-of-string positions inside a single string.

Or, if you need to use string iterpolation and use double quoted string literals, escape `$` to denote a literal `$` in the string, and escape the `$` inside the regex with `\\\`, triple backslashes (one escapes `$` for the PHP engine, and `\\` form a literal `\` that makes an escape symbol for regex special chars):

```
$str = "LIVR DEC 20 23 \$é**é$01\$";
$result = preg_replace("/\\\$[^ ]+\\\$/u", "", $str);
echo $result; // => LIVR DEC 20 23
```

See [another PHP demo](https://ideone.com/2HI0dP).